# Knot for adjusting the length of a loop using both ends of a cord

Tags: knots

I have a requirement where I want to tie a knot with the two ends of a cord where the length of the loop can be adjusted using either of the ends. (The knot has to be present on both the ends of the cord)

I want to use this to hang my compass/whistle (or any other smaller objects) around my neck while I go outdoors. While fixing the length of the cord would work in most of the cases, using an adjustable knot allows for the cord to be used by multiple people without retying or using a different length cord.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to outdoors.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Most of other knot questions don't specify that they are used in the outdoors but are considered ontopic, I don't see why this one wouldn't be.

Comment: Will those voting here kindly weigh in on this meta, please: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1154/9109.

Comment: @JamesJenkins A square knot does not meet the adjusted length requirement.  OK you could re-tie but pretty sure that is not what the OP is talking about.   A square knot would not work as well as a  double fisherman here.

Comment: @cobaltduck I'm voting to keep this open. This makes sense when you replace a pendant with a compass or a whistle that you need to tie up. Have expressed the same in the meta discussion.

Comment: Lito I suspect that the answer by mike is exactly what you are looking for, so your needs here are met.  We are discussing scope issues with your question and if it should stay as is or be modified to unquestionably be in scope.  I also suspect that you are asking about adjustable for aesthetic reasons, as you will be selling them (*which is fine*) but also further out of scope. Would you be ok with @Ricketyship (*or someone else*) significantly modifying you question to bringing it clearly into scope?

Comment: The question has been modified significantly to make it within scope. The answer in itself shows that this is a very useful question for anyone trying to carry stuff outdoors.

Answer (score 12):

A [double fishermans](http://www.animatedknots.com/doublefishermans/) can be adjusted for length by pulling on each knot and sliding them along the strand. You can also adjust the tail lengths and increase the number of turns to improve the appearance and use up extra slack.

Comment: Perfect answer.  The length is cut in 1/2 at most.  I use this on my bike to carry my keys.  I can shorten it up so they don't flop around.  Another good use is compass as can pull it out to use it.

Comment: Double fisherman is good. Taught Line Hitch is the first one that came into my head.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Mike's excellent answer I'd like to suggest replacing the barrel knots of the double fisherman's with [blake hitches](http://www.animatedknots.com/blakes/index.php). If properly dressed and set this will prevent the loop from sliding back to full length when under load, whereas the double fishermans slides a lot quicker.

Comment: The Double Fisherman's is the knot I remember and yes it did close up over time and with load. I will try using a barrel knot on one side and the firmer looking Blake hitch on the other.